# PHP form is not working

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to make an extremely simple form but it is not working for me. The point is a form where people write only their names and surnames, press "send" and done. I have writen the code below:

```
<form method="post" action="index_rost.php">

        <p>
          <label>name</label><br>
          <input name="name" placeholder="name here"><br><br>

          <label>surname</label><br>
          <input name="name2" placeholder="surname here"><br><br>

        </p>
        <p>
          <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="send it!"><br>
        </p>

            <?php
                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $name2 = $_POST['name2'];
                $from = 'website.se'; 
                $to = 'mymail@gmail.com, myothermail@gmail.com'; 
                $subject = 'new person is coming';


                $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
                $headers .= "From: $from". PHP_EOL;
                $headers .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8 ". PHP_EOL;

                $body = "<strong>From:</strong><br><br> $name $name2<br><br> <strong>Count on me, I want to come!</strong>";


                if ($_POST['submit'] && $name != '' && $name2 != '') {
                        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { 
                        echo '<p>Your name has been sent</p>';
                    } else { 
                        echo '<p>You need to fill up all fields</p>'; 
                    } 
                }

            ?>

      </form>
```

What happens is that besides no e-mail is sent to me, I get the error message (the one specified here: `else { echo '<p>You need to fill up all fields</p>'; } )` instead of the success message that I specify on the code. Can some one give me a hint of what is wrong?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: What error message you get

Comment: What isn't working? Can you give us an error message? We've going to need more information!

Comment: [Enable error reporting in PHP](http://blog.flowl.info/2013/enable-display-php-errors/)

Comment: The one I specified here: `else { 
                        echo '<p>You need to fill up all fields</p>'; 
                    } `

Comment: try to check your post variables with isset()

Comment: Turned on error reporting and got "Undefined index" errors on the lines `$name = $_POST['name'];`, `$name2 = $_POST['name2'];` and `if ($_POST['submit'] && $name != '' && $name2 != '') {`

Comment: Its better to use  if(!empty($name)){
   
    } rather than $name != ''

Answer (score 3):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

> mail() returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise.
>
> It is **important** to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.

You are getting a false back from `mail()` which means that the message is being **rejected** by whatever PHP is set up to use.

You can temporarily **use the following** to enable all errors and print those errors to the screen to give you an idea of what is failing.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

PHP will throw a notice such as the following which you can use to debug:

```
NOTICE (5): Unexpected Error: mail() [<a href='function.mail'>function.mail</a>]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "ip " port portip, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() (# 2).
```

Please remember, just because mail is accepted for delivery does **not** mean that it will arrive.

Comment: I just did that and I get the "Undefined index" errors on the lines `$name = $_POST['name'];`, `$name2 = $_POST['name2'];` and `if ($_POST['submit'] && $name != '' && $name2 != '') {`

Comment: @viriato See the first part of my answer.

Comment: @PezCuckow sure: "Notice: Undefined index: name in /customers/7/9/7/forall.se/httpd.www/index_rost.php on line 228 Notice: Undefined index: name2 in /customers/7/9/7/forall.se/httpd.www/index_rost.php on line 229 Notice: Undefined index: submit in /customers/7/9/7/forall.se/httpd.www/index_rost.php on line 242"

Comment: undefined index are warnings/notices, no errors. BEcause before you submit the form, the POST are not set

Comment: You can ignore the undefined index errors for now (though you should probably fix that see @jeroen's post), what error are you getting from mail when you **submit** the form?

Comment: I am not getting anything else. The only response I get from the form is that the error message that I specify on the code "You need to fill up all fields" is shown, and no mail is sent. I tried to use Firebug to see if I could see any other  error but it showed me nothing... :( @DanFromGermany, could you be more specific please?

Comment: It works fine on my local machine, if you are getting that message then `mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)` is returning false. If you're not seeing an error when enabling error reporting then I would like to guess your like your host has disabled `mail()`

Answer (score 1):

Currently when you just load the form (and before you submit anything) your entire code block is being run.

You should wrap your **whole** mail section in a block that is only exectuted when a POST request is made:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   // ...

}
```

That way you will not get any warnings about unset indices, etc.

About the mail problem, the `mail()` function returns `false`, so your message is not accepted for delivery. That could be any number of things on the server setup, but it could also be something simple, like you not specifying a valid e-mail address.

You should try changing:

```
$from = 'website.se';
```

to:

```
$from = 'a_valid_address@website.se';
```

Comment: But how do I do if I want to have a name only on $from?

Comment: @viriato You would need to set up an address that automatically deletes the mails, like `noreply@website.se`.

Comment: I meant a name, like a name of a website or my own name

Comment: @viriato That would probably be something like `Your Name <your@address.com>`

Answer (score 0):

Well it's pretty easy what is happening. I just formated it properly and... look what you're doing:

```
if ($_POST['submit'] && $name != '' && $name2 != '') {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { 
        echo '<p>Your name has been sent</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>You need to fill up all fields</p>'; 
    } 
}
```

All fields are set correctly, but mail() returns false.

Correct code would be:

```
if ($_POST['submit'] && $name != '' && $name2 != '') {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { 
        echo '<p>Your name has been sent</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Mail could not be sent</p>'; 
    } 
} else { 
    echo '<p>You need to fill up all fields</p>'; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, could you develop a little more? I don't understand where is my mistake...

Comment: Your message is not echoed if the form is empty, but if your mail could not be sent.

Comment: the question is, WHY can't the mail be sent